# How to link index to signup page?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I want to open the signup page through a button which I have made in *index.html* and I have given a link of signup but it is showing me that page is not found. Where is the problem?

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    return render(request, 'users/signup.html');
```

**main url page**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**app url page**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup')
]
```

**index.html**

```
<p><a href="{% static 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Signup</a></p>
```

**Folder structure**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<p><a href="{% static 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Signup</a></p>
```

Use:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Signup</a></p>
```

Here you need to use [**`url`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag, instead of static.